# Entity Framework inserts with sqltimestamp slow

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Im not sure if it relates but using EF 6.1.3 we are seeing slow inserts , we do maybe 1/2 million inserts, looking at the inserts its spends most of the time in reading ... due to sqltimestamp being retrieved is there a way to prevent this ?

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [trans].[HoleDetail]([HoleDetailId],  ...  )
VALUES (@0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, @1, @2, @3, NULL, @4, @5, NULL, @6, @7, @8, @9, NULL, NULL, NULL, @10, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, @11, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
SELECT [SyncUploadTime]
FROM [trans].[HoleDetail]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [HoleDetailId] = @0',N'@0 uniqueidentifier,@1 datetime2(7),@2 nvarchar(50),@3 uniqueidentifier,@4 float,@5 float,@6 uniqueidentifier,@7 tinyint,@8 datetime2(7),@9 uniqueidentifier,@10 tinyint,@11 datetime2(7)',@0='FFC43E14-EB59-4386-838E-3B90537A402F',@1='2015-07-28 00:53:04.3246383',@2=N'MMUBM140',@3='00000014-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',@4=19.100000381469727,@5=0.20000000298023224,@6='85215D76-B33A-4BB3-AA78-A4A9E2A60C86',@7=4,@8='2015-07-28 00:50:43.5835883',@9='9F884EF4-9E4F-484C-83BF-F8C62837E61A',@10=4,@11='2015-10-01 06:05:47.3934480'
```

Comment: Does `SyncUploadTime` property have `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute?

Comment: does SyncUploadTime has IsConcurrencyToken mapping ?

Comment: No its not the key  , used in concurrency or an identity.. key is the guid.